# ANY function returns nothing when the database is empty

Tags: neo4j, cypher, any

I have a cypher query which is looking to see if an account with a certain email address already exists in the database. To do this I use the built in `ANY` function:

```
MATCH (a:Account)
RETURN ANY(x IN a.email WHERE x='test@test.test') AS exists
```

since this is a development database the test records are sometimes deleted when a significant change to the data structure is made resulting in the database being empty. The problem I'm having is that the query shown above returns neither `true` or `false` instead it just returns nothing when the database is empty. This is problematic since this query is called by a php script using the `graph-aware` library and when I run the `getRecord()` it returns an error because the function returned nothing.

Is there a way to make the `ANY` function return `false` if the database is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The cypher-query can be simplified:

```
MATCH (a:Account) WHERE 'test@test.test' IN a.email
RETURN COUNT(a) > 0 AS exists
```

2) Use the driver features:

```
$result = $client->run('
  MATCH (a:Account) WHERE \'test@test.test\' IN a.email
  RETURN COUNT(a) > 0 AS exists
')

var_dump($result->size() && $result->getRecord())

// or      .

var_dump($result->firstRecordOrDefault(false))
```

Comment: Thanks, that’s exactly what I needed